# Flutter: How to rebuild an app on a certain event

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have an flutter web-app, it works for all screen sizes. I assigned an variable "width" to get the screen width and based on that entire app is built.

When I Zoom in or out on chrome, it requires me to refresh the page to get the desired sizes. Unless I refresh the widgets don't resize.

**I want a certain trigger like functionality, where if there is change in width, the app must rebuild.**

***How can I achieve this ?***

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to achieve this. This widget has a builder parameter that is called as the layout constraints change.

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {

    },
)
```

The constraints provide options that allow your application to understand how much space is available

```dart
constraints.maxWidth; // get maximum available width
constraints.maxHeight; // get maximum available height
constraints.minWidth; // get minimum available width
constraints.minHeight; // get minimum available height
```

These can be used to conditionally change the layout based on the available space and rebuilds at layout time.

Alternatively, you can use a simply `MediaQuery`. You can get width:

```dart
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

and height:

```dart
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

However, these calls must be done in the `build` method for the sizes to change with each rebuild.

Comment: I used MediaQuery to get width, I just want to trigger a rebuild when width changes.

Comment: @KaranOwalekar `build` is **already** called when the width changes. You're likely not doing the `MediaQuery`s in `build` like my answer says.

Comment: If i scale down to 50% then content looks small, but as soon as I hit refresh everything looks as I intended (at 50% settings). I want that refresh thing to happen

Comment: I'm using MediaQuery inside the build of the main file.

Comment: You have to share your code. I don't know what "scale down" means or exactly your issue or intended behavior is.

Comment: So I just used the print statement to monitor that. width is changing and build is running, problem is all widgets inside that are not building.

Comment: They almost definitely are building if "build is running". There is likely an error with your implementation.

Comment: But when I manually press hot-reload button it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219140/discussion-between-christopher-moore-and-karan-owalekar).